# How to move the gizmo of a section?

Tags: modeling, selection-tools, 3d-cursor, gizmo, tools

How to move the gizmo of a section of to make a scale (NOT relative to the center of the selection)? When I do it with the cursor it crushes all in 1 single point

Comment: Hello. From which part do you want to scale?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say section, I assume you mean selection or group of objects (more than one object).
First you move your 3d Cursor from the origin (0,0,0) to where you want to center your transform.

[image]

[image]

Then select your objects, set "Transition Orientation" to be relative to "Cursor", than any rotation or scale or move will be relative to that cursor point.

[image]

(please if this is your answer, please mark it as ANSWER so I can build credits)

Comment: I want to move the gizmo from a selection of edge to the left in the center of the mesh of the mesh then scale

Comment: there is no way to do it, except after making the selection and placing the cursor (i couldn't find how to move the cursor to the selection gizmo except by hand) then edit from there .

In Maya you unlock your gizmo, you move it where you want (do not modify the selection) then relock and you make the modification.

Comment: I would place the cursor first, then make the selection.   In an example (https://blend-exchange.com/b/Qw2vX3Jo/), I set the cursor to a selected vertex on Sphere.001, set transform pivot point to 3d Cursor, and then a rotate or scale is relative to that point.   I the VIEW tool, you can see the XYZ position of the cursor and change it precisely.   Or you could create an empty, position that and align the 3d cursor to the empty.   If this is nowhere near what you are looking for, then you might want to add detail to your description, especially a screenshot.